# Taking the minimum of a data set and transposing

Tags: excel, transpose

I am having an issue with my spreadsheet, I am trying to take the minimum value of a data set of one column on another sheet to get the minimum value for that set. However I have close to 100 columns and I cant seem to find a way of getting the cells to drag down and take the minimum of the cells.

I have tried to use the transpose function in excel to transpose the data horizontally which has worked to a certain extent however it looks terrible and as well as that it does not know when the cells are empty.

This is the raw data that I would like to analyze, I cannot change this format as it is copied in from another software and I want the spreadsheet to be user friendly. Each column is an individual data set.

[image: first photo]

This is what I want to extract from the data ie: the min max and average of each set.

[image: second photo]

I have used the following thus far to get the minimum value etc from the transposed data;

```
=IFERROR(IF(B6="","",ROUND(IF(MIN('4. Paste Raw Data'!DH4:AZJ4)=0,"",MIN('4. Paste Raw Data'!DH4:AZJ4)),3)),"")
```

Comment: You could probably do this pretty easily with `Power Query`.  With formulas, you could use `INDEX/MATCH` to return the entire relevant column as an array, and then apply `MIN`, `MAX`, etc to that result.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don´t need to transpose the data:

Try this one:

On your summary sheet, Cell B6:
`=MIN(OFFSET(4. Paste Raw Data!C7:C107,0,ROW()-6))`

Cell C6
`=MAX(OFFSET(4. Paste Raw Data!C7:C107,0,ROW()-6))`

Cell D6
`=AVERAGE(OFFSET(4. Paste Raw Data!C7:C107,0,ROW()-6))`

Then drag down the formulas.

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help, it just takes the min in the column C and If I drag it down it just takes the C+1 row value instead, I need it to go accross the columns not down the rows, does that make sense?

Comment: Did you place that formula? As soon as you drag it down, it is offseting on the columns, not the rows... Maybe it is just with " , " and not with " ; ". I will edit

Comment: When I pasted that formula into the cell and pressed enter a save window poped up? I have no idea why? After I hand typed it in it seemed to work, thanks so much for the simple fix!!

Comment: I am glad if it works for you. So please, click as answer and more people will find the same solution.